# twisted ReconnectingClientFactory fails without errors

Tags: python, twisted

What I have for you today is this log:

```
2014-11-17 08:26:35-0500 [-] Log opened.
2014-11-17 08:26:35-0500 [-] twistd 14.0.2 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.8) starting up.
2014-11-17 08:26:35-0500 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2014-11-17 08:26:35-0500 [-] Starting factory <crawl_client.WhoisClientProtocolFactory instance at 0x7fc162a36440>
2014-11-17 08:26:35-0500 [Uninitialized] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x7fc168b7fe60> will retry in 2 seconds
2014-11-17 08:26:35-0500 [Uninitialized] Stopping factory <crawl_client.WhoisClientProtocolFactory instance at 0x7fc162a36440>
2014-11-17 08:26:37-0500 [-] Starting factory <crawl_client.WhoisClientProtocolFactory instance at 0x7fc162a36440>
2014-11-17 08:26:37-0500 [Uninitialized] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x7fc168b7fe60> will retry in 4 seconds
2014-11-17 08:26:37-0500 [Uninitialized] Stopping factory <crawl_client.WhoisClientProtocolFactory instance at 0x7fc162a36440>
2014-11-17 08:26:42-0500 [-] Starting factory <crawl_client.WhoisClientProtocolFactory instance at 0x7fc162a36440>
2014-11-17 08:26:42-0500 [Uninitialized] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x7fc168b7fe60> will retry in 14 seconds
2014-11-17 08:26:42-0500 [Uninitialized] Stopping factory <crawl_client.WhoisClientProtocolFactory instance at 0x7fc162a36440>
2014-11-17 08:26:57-0500 [-] Starting factory <crawl_client.WhoisClientProtocolFactory instance at 0x7fc162a36440>
```

Here's the factory code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ReconnectingClientFactory
from uuid import uuid4

class WhoisClientProtocolFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):

  def __init__(self, clientName='', maxDelay=60):
    # attach a name with the client to identify itself to the server
    if not clientName:
      clientName = str(uuid4())[:8] # first 8 characters from a random string
    self.client_name = clientName
    self.maxDelay = maxDelay
    logFromClient("client started", logging.INFO, clientName)

  def buildProtocol(self, addr):
    self.resetDelay()
    return MyClientProtocol(self.client_name)
```

This code works fine on my test machine. When deployed on the server, it walks in circles. How can I put my hands on what's causing this?.
The client is based on `LineReceiver` by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a connection attempt fails, the factory's [`clientConnectionFailed`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory.html#clientConnectionFailed) method is called.  `ReconnectingClientFactory` implements this method to add the retry behavior and the minimal logging you saw giving the backoff timeout.

You can override this method too.  Introduce the extra logging you want - the reason the connection failed is passed as an argument to this method - and then call up to the base implementation (to preserve the retry behavior).

The reason is given as a [`Failure`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.failure.Failure.html) instance.

Comment: Thanks JPC!. The connection was being refused. I opened the port from `iptables` and now it's working.